# Serialize a single object?

Tags: python, django, json

I have a single object I want to serialize:

```
from django.core import serializers

...
    return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize("json", get_object_or_404(Animal, pk=1)), mimetype="application/json")
```

This throws a "Not Iterable" error, as it seems that it expects that the second parameter should be iterable. How can I serialize a single object to JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always wrap the object you want into a list and take back only the first element. Your second argument can be:

```
[get_object_or_404(Animal, pk=1),]
```

and when you deserialize,

```
my_obj = deserialize()[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `serializers.serialize` you need to pass an iterable (queryset). `get_object_or_404` returns a single object. In this case you need a queryset with that particular object (using `pk`). `filter` is what you need. Try something like:

```
return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize("json", Animal.objects.filter(pk=1)), mimetype="application/json")
```